# How to create an issue related to a pull request for a public Apache (or other) repository

Tags: apache, github, oozie, pull-request, issue-tracking

As an open source Oozie newbie user, I found the need of improving a few line of its source code, thus I forked another Oozie repository for myself, created a branch for the fix, pushed my change to that branch, and then made a `pull request` for that: ( https://github.com/mapr/oozie/pull/1 )

But based on github document, a `pull request` should correspond to an `ìssue`. As the Apache (or Mapr) repository is public (https://github.com/mapr/oozie), I cannot create an `issue` in `github`. So I only created the `issue` in apache `jira` (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-2646)

But in practice, my created issue in Jira and my `pull request` have not linked to each other at all. Anyone has suggestion on this impasse?

Comment: Since there's no generic/global right or wrong in this case, you should ask the project maintainers for help. I doubt this issue belongs outside of their project sphere. I'm sure they will appreciate you talking to them as well, they could probably guide you through the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The github repository is just a mirror, as shown by this screenshot:

[image]

So doing a pull request won't help. The correct way to submit a code change is explained [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OOZIE/How+To+Contribute).